# ReSharper intellisense does not display documentation

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-7.1

Any idea why I'm not getting any documentation to go along with my ReSharper IntelliSense?  If I go to the ReSharper options and enable the Visual Studio IntelliSense instead, I get the proper documentation when going through the members in the IntelliSense pop up.  If I re-enable the ReSharper IntelliSense, I now get the ReSharper IntelliSense pop up sans documentation.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Go to `ReSharper | Options -> Environment | IntelliSense | Completion Appearance`. Check `Show member signatures` and `Show summary`.

Comment: Why on earth would this be off by default? Is there any downside to enabling it (like slower performance)?

Comment: All the performance penalty in the world wouldn't convince me to disable the documentation!

Comment: @joneberg this is because a lot of people complaining that documentation often eats a lot of screen space and hides a lot of code so they are losing context and forced to press `Esc` to often.

Comment: If someone from JetBrains ReSharper team is reading this - please turn these on by default!

Comment: This does not work for me. Switching to Visual Studio intellisense does so its definitely a problem with Resharper.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same problem, but following the above does not solve it.

Comment: I guess i found it. Check my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

For those who, like me, tried the solution provided above and it didn't work. I found this [article](http://rionscode.wordpress.com/2013/06/28/a-battle-of-intellisense/) and it did the trick for me.

Go to Tools - Options - Text Editor - C# (or all Languages, or whatever you need).
In the general section, the options `Auto list Members` and `Parameter information` must be enabled. (I suppose only `Parameter Information` would be fine to, but i enabled the other one anyway as its a nice feature).

Comment: This way you turn on Visual Studio builtin intellisense, not ReSharper one. And if you have ReSharper installed and have both Visual Studio and ReSharper intellisense turned on, you would really have battle of intellisenses.

Comment: I see your point, but it only turns on this single specific feature of vs's intellisense, I have no problems so far.

Comment: No, it turns on the whole VS intellisense, not a "single specific feature"

Comment: i tried this and the above answer and (still) did not work. So unfortunately I will have to deal with it :)