# Resharper hiding documentation

Tags: resharper

Resharper has a "feature" that seems to hide parameter information, XML based documentation, and just about anything useful in Intellisense. I wish to disable this "feature". **Note: I have seen Resharper not disable parameter information before, so I know it's possible, somehow.**

Here's what Visual Studio's parameter information looks like with Resharper disabled:

[image]

And this is what Resharper's information looks like:

[image]

As can be seen, Resharper's "feature" here is beyond useless. I have tried to resolve this by following **all** the steps in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411014/resharper-intellisense-does-not-display-documentation) and given that question was asked over 3 years ago, my question is not a duplicate. After over 3 years I was hoping this had been fixed, because it must be a bug, there's no sane reason for this to even exist.

How do I get parameter information back?

Comment: Have you tried with other methods? E.g: string.IsNullOrEmpty(), because in my case it's displaying properly except for the Regex methods. Maybe this specific class doesn't have XML documentation (weird though).

Answer (score 1):

It is [a known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-465412) if XML doc file for a library has "redirect" attribute for `<doc>` tag, e.g.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc redirect="%PROGRAMFILESDIR%Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.X\mscorlib.xml" />
```

The issue has been fixed in [R# 2017.2 EAP builds](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/eap/).